# wordpress login loop after install

Tags: admin, wp-admin, installation

I spun up a AWS instance to run a LAMP stack + the latest Wordpress (4.1.1).

I am doing everything from the command line as root and do not use Cpanel or phpMyAdmin

After creating the user + DB and pointing the apache root dir to the directory where WP was extracted to I edited the wp-config file and opened the installer page in my browser. Install completes and I am redirected to the admin login page.

And then the fun starts....

When I try to login to the admin area after entering my user/pass I get an endless loop of redirects to the admin login page.

The actual WP site comes up just fine.

Here are some of the things I have tried (many based on Google searches)

- tried to access the site with different browsers
- clear cache/cookies
- dropped the DB and reinstalled
- extracted the files again
- changed file/Dir perms
- added define statements to handle cookies
- kill the instance and started from scratch using the yum WP package
- Set define('WP_DEBUG', true)

The only thing I haven't tried is using a .htaccess file. Is it mandatory to have one with WP 4.1 ?? what should it contain ?

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Did you change your host and the htaccess files contain basically permission redirection :)?

Comment: Are the any plugins involved in the install? What do the Apache logs tells you?